# Excel array formula for max with multiple/ variable criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet that contains 365 rows, representing dates from a referred Start Date (for the following year). There are about 30 columns each of which has an agency name.
The cells in the sheet contain calculated agency populations for each date.

This is a reference sheet: `"DailyPopulation"`

In the `ReportSheet` the user defines a *Period Start Date* and *Period End Date*

I'm trying to construct an array formula that displays the max population for each agency within the defined period, separately (of course) I also want the min.

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table.  With Excel 2010 you can use slicers to filter for your data

Comment: Hey Beard, Have thought of that.  Unfortunately I'm stuck (corporately) with Excel 2003.  It's a good approach though so I'll have a play.

Answer (score 2):

Where your Start Date is in `B1`, your End Date is in `B2`, all the dates are in `A2:A366` on the DailyPopulation sheet, and the data for the agency in question is in `B2:B365` on the DailyPopulation sheet, you can use the following array formula.

```
=MAX(IF($B$1<=DailyPopulation!$A$2:$A$366,IF($B$2>=DailyPopulation!$A$2:$A$366,DailyPopulation!B$2:B$366,""),""))
```

Remember you must enter the formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  If you arrange your ReportSheet with each agency in a different column, you can fill this formula to the right.

To find the minimum, just replace `MAX` with `MIN`.