# Excel: What formula to use to return the minimum or maximum of a set of lookup values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I'm looking for a way to calculate the values shown in cols D & E in the below screengrab.  Column D contains the earliest date from column B where the name in column A matches.  Similarly, column E contains the latest date from column C where the name in column A matches.

[image]

e.g. For all instances of "Bob" in column A: column D should contain the earliest "Line from date" from column B where column A="Bob" (in this case 1st December 2013).

I know this can be done easily using a pivot table, however in this case I need to do it with either a formula or programatically.

The data is being generated using VBA so, in the absence of a formulaic solution, I will simply revert to calculating the required values as part of the program (NB: I am not asking how to do this).  Because of the dataset's complexity (the above example is a gross simplification) it would take me about a day to implement it in code so I'd rather avoid that if possible.

I'm guessing the way to go might be array formulas, but I am ashamed to admit I haven't the first clue how to use them.

Any and all help/pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? - Based on the simplified screenshot above, what value would you want to return? What is the logic in simple words? Your question title says "highest/lowest lookup value from a table". Nice buzz words. How do they relate to the data sample?

Comment: The required return values for each row are shown in columns D&E. For each row I want to compare all rows with matching values in column A (e.g. when calculating D5 and E5 I would be looking at rows 3, 5 and 6) and, for column D return the minimum value of column B from the matching rows, for column E return the maximum value of column C from the matching rows.

Comment: e.g. The values in D3, D5 and D6 are all the same and equal the minimum of B3, B5 and B6.  Similarly E3, E5 and E6 in the example are all the same and equal the maximum of C3, C5 and C6.

Comment: Fine. Update your question to reflect these requirements. Comments are not meant to be used to describe the use case.

Comment: That does not make much sense. Prepare a sample file with the "before" and the "after" scenario. Post it on your favourite file sharing site and share a link here. Describe your requirements in plain words that form rules. Update your question to reflect these requirements. In short: manually mock up what you want to see as the result of automation. Provide sample files and the rules that lead from current state to desired state.

Comment: Obviously it's not my decision to make, but I'd say that whilst the solution to [Excel array formula for max with multiple/ variable criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/458898/excel-array-formula-for-max-with-multiple-variable-criteria) employs the same calculation method, the original condition is sufficiently different for this not to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

```
{=MIN(IF(MatchRange=MatchVal,ValueRange))}
```

or

```
{=MAX(IF(MatchRange=MatchVal,ValueRange))}
```

So, translated to the conditions of the original example...

Cell D2 would contain the following array formula:

```
{=MIN(IF(A$2:A$7=A2),B$2:B$7)}
```

And cell E2 would contain:

```
{=MAX(IF(A$2:A$7=A2),C$2:C$7)}
```

NB: Don't type the braces/curly brackets in the above examples.  Enter the formula without them then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create an array formula.

The formulas in D2:E2 would then be "autofillable" to D2:E7.

With endless gratitude to teylyn, without whose helpful comments I might've just sat here waiting for an answer like a noob.

Comment: I think it's work stating in the answer that to put in an array formula you need to use ctrl+shift+enter and not put explicitly put the curly brackets around it.